# Create a new BasicOverposterLayerProperties

Tags: arcobjects, labeling, convert, annotation, maplex

ArcGIS 10.1 with VB.NET

I have been trying to figure this out for days but can't seem to make the connection. For a layer I am trying to create a label. I create a new  BasicOverposterLayerProperties

```
Dim pBasicOverposterLayerProps As IBasicOverposterLayerProperties4 = New BasicOverposterLayerProperties
        <setup properties>
        Dim pAnnoLayerProps As IAnnotateLayerProperties = Nothing
        Dim pAnnoLayerPropsColl As IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection = pGeoFeatLayer.AnnotationProperties
        pAnnoLayerPropsColl.QueryItem(0, pAnnoLayerProps, Nothing, Nothing)
        Dim pLabelEngineLayerProps As ILabelEngineLayerProperties2 = CType(pAnnoLayerProps, ILabelEngineLayerProperties2)

pLabelEngineLayerProps.BasicOverposterLayerProperties = CType(pBasicOverposterLayerProps, IBasicOverposterLayerProperties)
```

Setup all my label properties and apply it and it works great for the ESRI Standard Labeling Engine. Now with the widespread use of Maplex I want to convert the labeling properties before applying.

```
Dim pUidOld As UID = New UID
Dim pUidNew As UID = New UID
pUidOld.Value = "{01004145-0D1C-11D2-A26F-080009B6F22B}" 'ESRI Standard Label Engine
pUidNew.Value = "{20664808-0D1C-11D2-A26F-080009B6F22B}" 'ESRI Maplex Label Engine
Dim pAnnotationPropertiesConverter As MaplexAnnotationPropertiesConverter = New MaplexAnnotationPropertiesConverter

Dim pGeomType As esriGeometryType = pFeatCls.ShapeType 
Dim pDisplayTrans As IDisplayTransformation = MyDoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation
Dim pAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollectionOld As IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection = ???

Dim pAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollectionNew As IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection = pAnnotationPropertiesConverter.Convert(pGeomType, pDisplayTrans, pUidOld, pAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollectionOld, pUidNew)
```

I can't figure out how to get the pAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollectionOld object from the pBasicOverposterLayerProps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the Maplex Overposter?

Something like (it's in C# but you should be able to convert to VB):

```
IAnnotateMap maplexEngine = (IAnnotateMap) new MaplexAnnotateMapClass();
map.AnnotationEngine = maplexEngine;

// Set the label placement to be "best" quality
IMapOverposter mapOverposter = (IMapOverposter)map;
IMaplexOverposterProperties mapOverposterProps = (IMaplexOverposterProperties)mapOverposter.OverposterProperties;
mapOverposterProps.PlacementQuality = esriMaplexPlacementQuality.esriMaplexPlacementQualityHigh;
mapOverposter.OverposterProperties = (IOverposterProperties)mapOverposterProps;
```